# SQL SERVER Contagem de dados de um registro

Tags: sql, count

Deparei com a seguinte situação:

A tabela  abaixo é um checklist e possui uma coluna de convênios, as outras são perguntas respondidas com sim(1), não(0) e semPreenchimento(null ou 9).

Queria contar em cada convenio quantas das perguntas foram respondidas com sim, não ou semPreenchimento... nesse momento não importa o nome da coluna.

Qual a estrutura ideal para esse tipo de situação ou qual Query atenderia essa necessidade.

Pois posteriormente vou agrupar os convênios por região e apresentar o percentual de preenchimento por região.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Muito boa a pergunta Paulo! +1

Answer (score 4):

Você pode usar o `SUM` mas tem dois pontos:
- Somar todas as colunas
- Agrupar por cada sim/não/sem preenchimento

Daria para fazer num único `SELECT`, somando as colunas (`sum(col1)+sum(col2)+...`), mas teria o problema dos valores individuais...
Então poderia usar um `CASE WHEN`: (`sum(CASE WHEN col1=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)`)  para cada valor e cada coluna...

Essa é uma opção:

```
select idConvenio, 
       (SUM(CASE WHEN EnderecoSi=0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
        SUM(CASE WHEN EnderecoSit=0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
        SUM(CASE WHEN EnderecoContr=0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
        SUM(CASE WHEN EnderecoFis=0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
        SUM(CASE WHEN RazaoSi=0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
        SUM(CASE WHEN RazaoSit=0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) TOT_0
        ,        
       (SUM(CASE WHEN EnderecoSi=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
        SUM(CASE WHEN EnderecoSit=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
        SUM(CASE WHEN EnderecoContr=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
        SUM(CASE WHEN EnderecoFis=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
        SUM(CASE WHEN RazaoSi=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
        SUM(CASE WHEN RazaoSit=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) TOT_1
        ,
        (SUM(CASE WHEN EnderecoSi=9 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
        SUM(CASE WHEN EnderecoSit=9 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
        SUM(CASE WHEN EnderecoContr=9 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
        SUM(CASE WHEN EnderecoFis=9 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
        SUM(CASE WHEN RazaoSi=9 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
        SUM(CASE WHEN RazaoSit=9 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) TOT_9
from exemplo
group by idConvenio
```

Veja aqui o fiddle funcionando: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/0283c/10

Uma observação do CASE WHEN: quando acha um valor (0,1 ou 9) retorna 1, para somar uma ocorrência, senão retorna 0, ignorando.

Fiz o exemplo com 6 colunas apenas para agilizar, mas basta adicionar as demais, isso supondo que não tenha muitas.

Outra opção seria fazer duas queries, uma agrupando só sim/não/sem preenchimento, colocar numa CTE e depois agrupar novamente e somar.

Comment: deixe ela @JoãoMartins, é uma outra alternativa, pode servir para outros cenários, opções são sempre bem vindas

Comment: Ok, bem visto ;). Resposta mantida.

Answer (score 1):

Penso que assim consegue o que pretende:

```
SELECT      iConvenio
        ,   COUNT(1) AS resposta
INTO        #tmpSim
FROM        tabela
WHERE       EnderecoSi      = 1
        OR  EnderecoSit     = 1
        OR  EnderecoContr   = 1
--      OR  ...
GROUP BY    iConvenio

SELECT      iConvenio
        ,   COUNT(1) AS resposta
INTO        #tmpNao
FROM        tabela
WHERE       EnderecoSi      = 0
        OR  EnderecoSit     = 0
        OR  EnderecoContr   = 0
--      OR  ...
GROUP BY    iConvenio

SELECT      iConvenio
        ,   COUNT(1) AS resposta
INTO        #tmpSemPreenchimento
FROM        tabela
WHERE       ISNULL(EnderecoSi, 9)       = 9
        OR  ISNULL(EnderecoSit, 9)      = 9
        OR  ISNULL(EnderecoContr, 9)    = 9
--      OR  ...
GROUP BY    iConvenio

SELECT      iConvenio
        ,   SUM(sim)                AS sim
        ,   SUM(nao)                AS nao
        ,   SUM(sempreenchimento)   AS sempreenchimento
FROM        (
                SELECT  iConvenio
                    ,   resposta    AS sim
                    ,   0           AS nao
                    '   0           AS sempreenchimento
                FROM    #tmpSim
                UNION ALL
                SELECT  iConvenio
                    ,   0           AS sim
                    ,   resposta    AS nao
                    ,   0           AS sempreenchimento
                FROM    #tmpNao
                UNION ALL
                SELECT  iConvenio
                    ,   0           AS sim
                    ,   0           AS nao
                    ,   resposta    AS sempreenchimento
                FROM    #tmpSemPreenchimento
            ) X
GROUP BY    iConvenio
```

Se não quiser (ou não puder) utilizar tabelas temporárias, pode sempre passar todo esse código para dentro do `SUBSELECT` do `FROM`.

Comment: Show!!! Duas ideias muito boas, obrigado pela atenção.